# Embedding of central simple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

A paper I am reading has the following statement (without proof):

If $B$ and $A$ are central simple algebras with the same center $K$
where $K$ is a local or a global field, then $B$ can be embedded into $A$
if and only if [B : K] is relatively prime with $[A : K]/[B : K]$.

The necessity is fairly easy to show. But how does one show the sufficiency?

Comment: If $[A : K] = [B : K]$, it sounds like you're saying that any two central simple algebras of the same dimension can be embedded into each other, which can't be right.

Comment: I assumed it was supposed to exclude the case where $[A:K] = [B:K]$. But it still does not seem likely even when you exclude that case. Must be a typo in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very unlikely to me. What if $A$ is a division algebra
and $B$ is a matrix algebra over $K$? (When $K=\Bbb Q_p$, theses exist with any given square degree over $K$.)

The other way round sounds fishy too. Over $K=\Bbb Q_p$ there are
division algebras $A$ and $B$ with $|A:K|=16$ and $|B:K|=4$
and with $B$ a subalgebra of $A$.

Comment: If $A\rightarrow B$ is an embedding of $K$-CDA's of dimension $4$ and $16$, then $B\cong A\times Cent_B(A)$ and $Cent_B(A)$ is a $K$-CSA of dimension $4$. Now, $A$ and  $Cent_B(A)$ are $4$-torsion and $B$ is of order $16$ in $Br(K)$.